Getting Input and Output token counts with LangChain
I've found it difficult to find any straightforward way to get input and output tokens from LangChain when calling an LLM.  All the LLM-specific libraries I've worked with provide this easily with a simple call after calling the LLM and getting a response.
Can anyone provide code examples for what I hope will be a simple library method call to get Input and Output tokens from a returned LLM call in LangChain?

You can use community callbacks for this. Example usage:
from langchain_community.callbacks import get_openai_callback
from langchain_openai import OpenAI

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
with get_openai_callback() as cb:
    llm.invoke("What is the square root of 4?")

total_tokens = cb.total_tokens
assert total_tokens > 0

If you prefer, you can write a custom handler which can contain the token counting logic:
from langchain_core.callbacks import BaseCallbackHandler
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_openai.chat_models import ChatOpenAI


class MyCustomHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    def on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(f"My custom handler, token: {token}")


prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(["Tell me a joke about {animal}"])

model = ChatOpenAI(streaming=True, callbacks=[MyCustomHandler()])

chain = prompt | model

response = chain.invoke({"animal": "bears"})

more on https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/modules/callbacks/custom_callbacks/
https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/modules/callbacks/token_counting/
